# PHP array returning NULL in page after file include

Tags: php, ajax, single-page-application

Thanks in advance for the help! I've run across a weird issue and just can't figure out where this data is dropping off! I'm loading a PHP page in with AJAX on a single page web app (update-inventory.php). At the top of the page I'm pulling in, I require_once a config file that has absolute paths for some functions files as well as a couple require_once includes.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
//The above config.php file pulls in the $vendorArray data
//Below I echo it to see if it's there
echo "<br><pre>In the update-inventory.php file<br>";
var_export($vendorArray);
echo "<br></pre>";
?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

In the config.php file:

```
if( isset($Modules['Retail']) || array_key_exists('Retail', $Modules) ) {
define('RETAIL_DIR', blah blah blah);
  if( file_exists(RETAIL_DIR . '/_functions.php') ) {
    require_once RETAIL_DIR . '/_functions.php';
  }else{
    error_log('retail module file _functions.php was not found');
  }
  if( file_exists(RETAIL_DIR . '/_page-variables.php') ) {
    require_once RETAIL_DIR . '/_page-variables.php';
  }else{
    error_log('retail module file _page-variables.php was not found');
  }
  // echo "Retail Module Loaded<br>";
}
```

The variable in question ($vendorArray) is specified in the _page-variables.php file and is echoed out just fine:

```
$vendorArray = getVendors();//getVendors is in the _functions.php file
echo "<br><pre>In the _page-variables.php file<br>";
var_export($vendorArray);
echo "<br></pre>";
echo "page variables loaded";
```

So I do not understand how the included file of _page-variables.php echoes out $vendorArray just fine but then the var_export in my webpage which is the next action in my page, returns NULL!
This is what I'm seeing on my webpage at the very top prior to the rest of the page loading just fine:

```
In the _page-variables.php file
array (
  20 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'AZ Patio Heaters',
    'vshort' => 'azpatheat',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'General Metals',
    'vshort' => 'gmc01',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'Perfect Patio, LLC',
    'vshort' => 'pp01',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'Poundex Associates Corp.',
    'vshort' => 'pound01',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'TK Classics',
    'vshort' => 'tkc01',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'Trivantage',
    'vshort' => 'tri01',
  ),
)
page variables loaded
In the update-inventory.php file
NULL
```

Somebody with a bigger brain than mine, please help! lol
[image: $vendorArray error]

Comment: Is `$Modules` defined anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your code to try to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, just above the if statement i have $Modules = getModuleInfo(); and the getModuleInfo() is a function in the _functions.php file that is included.

Comment: @Difster The code was working perfectly as a stand-alone page.. before I started AJAXing it in.

Comment: But functions is included after the isset check on $modules

Comment: I apologize for the confusion there @apokryfos I actually have a main _functions.php file that is included above that where my main functions reside, like getModuleInfo().. and I also have a _functions.php file included that is part of the $Modules['Retail'] module I load into the program.

Comment: Added picture of the rendered webpage.. same variable var_export-ed.. the first result is correct but the code is in the included _page-variables.php file, the second result is NULL and the code is directly in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to use global on the $vendorArray variable.. which means I need to restructure my code I guess since global is considered a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

I can just imagine three things:

1. The if-statement fails and the config isn't loaded (check other variables).
2. The function getVendors() depends on some environment variables which change from script to script, like some information about the current path, etc.
3. You are not loading all the stuff you need.

Comment: These are comments, not answers.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll look into those points. I do know that the if-statement does not fail, which is why I'm able to var_export the data in the included file, _page-variables.php

Comment: I'm currently not able to make comments, because I have less than 50 reputation. Your down vote doesn't really help to solve this "issue". I completely agree with you, but I think it's better to make a comment as a post, than to say nothing. It maybe helps him.

Comment: getVendors() is just a database query that is returned as a variable named $vendorArray.. no paths or anything that would affect it.